# Dell BIOS, different boot entry after Auto-On-Time event

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, dell-latitude, dell-optiplex

I want to make use of the Auto-On-Time feature in my Dell Latitude E7250. This feature sets the time of day when the system will turn on automatically. Is it possible to mod the BIOS to allow it to boot a different boot entry than default?

I am looking for an universal solution that will also work for Optiplex machines.

This is what I have already tried:

1. Download the BIOS from [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=4rjkx&oscode=wb64a&productcode=latitude-e7250-ultrabook)
2. Extract it using [Dell PFS Update Extractor](https://github.com/platomav/BIOSUtilities#dell-pfs-update-extractor)
3. Open `1 E7250A24 -- 1 System BIOS with BIOS Guard vA.24.bin` file with [UEFITool](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool)

I am stuck at this point. I don't know where the Auto-On-Time feature is located and how to decompile it.

Comment: You can't mod the BIOS - it is digitally signed by Dell.

Comment: For sure there is some way to go around it...

Comment: Certainly not the way you're thinking.

Comment: Every virus-writer would just love to know of a way to go around it ...

Comment: Interesting problem, but yea, modifying the BIOS isn't going to work on any sort of modern computer. As others have noted: that is simply too big a security hole to be a viable solution. Even if it works today, it won't tomorrow. An alternate option would be to install a different bootloader that can handle this. BIOS will Auto-On to the bootloader, and the bootloader will load the boot entry you want.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why you might want to do what you are describing

However, Dell is not going to give you any way to "decompile" and/or rebuild the BIOS/UEFI for their systems

The security concerns are astronomical

Even if you could figure it out, which seems *highly* implausible, it will be prevented by the system as soon as the next update from Dell drops

What you have described is a way to takeover any system for malicious use by anyone ...that just is not going to fly

If you want to change what boots *by default* (which is what is going to boot when the system starts), then *change the default* in your bootloader

Or change the boot order of the drives in your BIOS (which has the same effect) - so long as one of those other devices has the OS you want to load when it starts up if you do not manually intervene